# Weird Angular Fire error re FetchXmlHttpFactory

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, build-error

I am getting this weird error trying to build an Angular project. The full error is:

> export 'FetchXmlHttpFactory' (imported as 'v') was not found in '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper' (possible exports: ErrorCode, Event, EventType, Stat, WebChannel, XhrIo, createWebChannelTransport, default, getStatEventTarget)

I have never seen this error before. This is a brand new Angular project created through  Angular CLI v12. I created the project, added a few dependencies (including @angular/fire) and copied over some components from another project. I use AngularFire all the time but have never seen anything like this and I can't find any mention of this error on the web.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Frank. I should have checked before I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was recently fixed with the firebase-js-sdk, try updating to the latest Firebase libraries and dependencies, specifically the web wrapper mentioned here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/4982

Source:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4977#issuecomment-854857934

Comment: Just for information, I also found this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4984